# Calling servlet from HTML form, but servlet is never invoked

Tags: java, html

Iam calling servlet from html form,servlet takes the form data and it will insert that form data into database.But when i click the submit button error page is coming.please help whats wrong in my servlet code.

my servlet code:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;




public class Loginservlet extends HttpServlet {

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException
  {
    System.out.println("login servlet");
  String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
  Connection connection=null;
  res.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
  String username= req.getParameter("username");
  String password = req.getParameter("password");
   try {
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root"); 
   String sql = "insert into signup values (?,?)";
  PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
  pst.setString(1, username);
  pst.setString(2, password);

  int numRowsChanged = pst.executeUpdate();
    out.println(" Data has been submitted ");

  pst.close();
  }
  catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
  out.println("Couldn't load database driver: "+ e.getMessage());
  }
  catch(SQLException e){
  out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  catch (Exception e){
  out.println(e);
  }
  finally {
  try {
  if (connection != null) 
      connection.close();
  }
  catch (SQLException ignored){
  out.println(ignored);
  }
  }
  }
}
```

my html code:

Sign Up

```
       <form action="servlet/Loginservlet"  method="post" >

                 <font size='5'>Create your Account:</font><br/><br>

                    <label for="username" accesskey="u" style="padding-left:3px;">User Name: </label>

                                    <input type="text" style="background-color:#ffffff;margin-left:14px;padding-top:7px;border-width:0px;margin-top:6px;padding-right:85px;" id="username" name="username" tabindex="1"><br/><br>

                    <label for="password" accesskey="p" style="padding-left:4px;">Password: </label>

                                    <input type="password" style="background-color:#ffffff;margin-left:14px;padding-top:7px;border-width:0px;padding-right:85px;" id="password" name="pasword" tabindex="2"><br/><br>


                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-left:164px;"/>

                    <input type="reset" value="Reset" style="margin-left:17px;"/>

    </form>
```

web.xml file:

```
                  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                      <web-app version="2.5" 
                        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

                           <servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Loginservlet</servlet-class>
                          </servlet>
                         <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
                       </servlet-mapping>
```

please help

Comment: You should also post an excerpt of your used `web.xml` file

Comment: which error comes? and is there any exception in console as well?

Comment: As fyr points, you have to register the servlet at an URL so the server uses it. If you have done it, check console/logs to see if there is some exception while loading the servlet class/instantiating it.

Comment: @fyr:now i posted web.xml file

Answer (score 1):

check  `web.xml` file of your project, you have to registrate your servlet there.[check this](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/servlet/tutorial/helloworld/index.xtp) also

use `<form action="/login"  method="post" >` in html
and

in web.xml

```
<servlet-class>your.class.package.Loginservlet</servlet-class>
                          </servlet>
```

Comment: yeah i registered my servlet in web.xml file

Comment: i am doing programming in Myeclipse IDE

Answer (score 1):

As you look into your servlet class, there is no `package` defined, which is required. And map that class with package(mean fully qualified name) in `<servlet-class/>` tag.

Another thing is you are setting action to url `servlet/LogininServlet`, but given different url in `<url-pattern/>` tag, which is wrong. you can simply set the form action to `login`

Comment: are you getting 404 or any other error page?

Comment: its not 404 error page....it is "this program can not display webpage."

Answer (score 0):

everything is fine....in the html page use action="./login".........it will work i have done the same

Comment: the dot before the slash should do the trick